# karma: unit testing controller that listens on angular-ui-router event

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, karma-runner

I try to unit test an angularJS controller with Kara/Sinon/Jasmine.
The controller listens to state changes from angular-ui-router to call a service.

I stubbed the service method (*update*) using sinon and i use $broadcast to throw the event in the tests.
I use $apply to fire the event.

However, it seems the controller does not seem to react.

I try to check for teh sinon stubbed method and i also use console.log to see weather or not the controller reacts - but it does not.
It does in the manual browser test, so i guess it is my test that needs to be fixed (*should be the other way round, i know*).

What am i doing wrong here?

the karma test specs:

```
'use strict';    
describe('controllers', function() {
    beforeEach(module('myApp.controllers'));
    beforeEach(module('myApp.services'));
    beforeEach(module('ui.router'));

    describe('myAppController', function() {
        var scope, ctrl;

        beforeEach(inject(function(
            $rootScope, $controller, $injector,ParamsHelper) {

            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            scope.ParamsHelperStub  = sinon.stub(ParamsHelper, 'update');

            ctrl = $controller('myAppController', {
                $scope: scope,
                ParamsHelper: scope.ParamsHelperStub
            });


        }));

        it('should use ParamsHelper if is deepLink', function() {
            var event       = {};
            var toState     = {name:'regions'};
            var toParams    = ['test'];
            scope.AppSettingsStub.state.isDeepLink = true;
            scope.$broadcast("$stateChangeStart", event, toState, toParams);
            scope.$apply();

            expect(scope.ParamsHelperStub.calledWith(['test'])).toBeTruthy();
        });

    });
});
```

From the controller:

```
...

rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
  function(event, toState, toParams) {
    console.log('VibeController: $stateChangeStart Event catched');
    ParamsHelper.update(toParams);

    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in the scope.
To fire an event that can be recognized by the controller i need to fire it in the rootScope context.

I added the rootScope in the initial injection and then edited the broadcasting command accordingly:

```
describe('myAppController', function() {
  var scope, ctrl, rootScope;

  beforeEach(inject(function(
    $rootScope, $controller, $injector, ParamsHelper) {

    rootScope = $rootScope;

    ...

    rootCope.$broadcast("$stateChangeStart", event, toState, toParams);
```

Comment: How to tell stateChangeStart the state we are changing to, e.g. I want  "toState" to be "auth.signin" and then to be able to check "toState.authenticate" which I defined in my routes.

Comment: @SirBenBenji Maybe ask that as a new Question? Partialy because i do not quite get what it is you want to do :-)